# Applozic UI: adding custom options

Tags: applozic

My app is using Applozic's UI. When you are looking at a chat conversation and hold down on a message, you are given the following Message Options: copy, forward, reply. I am hoping to add another option for group messages-- 'Reply privately', which would create a new conversation between you and whoever sent that message.
Is this possible?

I'm looking at the project in GitHub and don't know where to begin:
https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK

Applozic's documentation does not cover this, and getting in contact with their support is kind of a headache.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by importing source code in your project and adding an option, handling the event click of that option

This are the step you can follow to achieve it.

1. You can import the source code from this doc [link](https://docs.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-theme-and-customization#section-ui-source-code) and make sure to fork the GitHub repo and import the source code from forked GitHub repo [link](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK).
   If any new changes or release comes you can merge the changes from the master of the GitHub repo in the forked
2. Create a string with name `chat_private` in strings.xml file in the module `mobicomkitui` folder res dir and set the value for string name `chat_private`

Example :    `<string name="chat_private">Private Reply</string>`

3.In `DetailedConversationAdapter` file find the method `onCreateContextMenu`  and add this below code in side the for `for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {`

```
   if (menuItems[i].equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.chat_private)) && channel == null && message.isTypeOutbox()) {
                continue;
            }
```

4.Open `MobiComConversationFragment` file and find the method  `public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {`
 and add below code

```
    case 8:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ConversationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ConversationUIService.USER_ID, message.getContactIds());
            if (message.getConversationId() != null) {
                intent.putExtra(ConversationUIService.CONVERSATION_ID, message.getConversationId());
            }
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            break;
```